# Find out which design is best

Tags: user-research

I have two designs which I would like to send to our customers to find out which one they would rather use. What would be the best way to collect the results for this?

Thanks
Steve

Answer (score 1):

This might lead to personalized and biased opinions from the users as they will always like one better than the other.

I prefer [A/B Testing](https://www.optimizely.com/ab-testing/) in such cases because it helps me figure out what right and what is wrong in each approach.

This helps get more streamlined feedback

Comment: Hi, I would very much like to A/B test them. The problem is that the company would like to get feedback on which one to develop before launch so we only spend time developing one solution and then once live we can invest time in a/b testing against that solution.

Comment: Probably be best with a fully functioning prototype in that case, using something like InVision and then carry out some user surveys. That said, the usability, design and functionality of your website should've been driven by your users in the first place.